# Why selly api is showing only 20 products of the +400 I have?

Tags: javascript, php

I have +400 products on selly.io but when I connect the API on my custom website it show only 20 products.

By the way it's not reading the embed script and still don't know how to solve it, If anyone can help me I'll appreciate it very much.

I can pay for help too but not to much since I'm break at the moment, I paid 2 developers to help me and they didn't knew how to fix it, so basically I got scammed.

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
> https://embed.selly.io/index.map: HTTP error: status code 403,
> net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

This is my code :

```
const getData = () => {
  const apiKey = "************";
  const apiEmail = "************";
  const apiToken = `${apiEmail}:${apiKey}`;
  const encode = btoa(apiToken);
  axios
    .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +
        "https://selly.gg/api/v2/products",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${encode}`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      res.data.forEach((element) => {
        const itemsContainer = document.getElementById("items");
        const content = `<div class="tile">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/lHSV5iP.png" alt="vivek" />
        </div>
        <h3 id="title">${element.title}</h3>
        <button class="purchase" data-selly-product="${element.id}">Purchase</button>
        <p class="stocks"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> ${element.stock} in stocks</p>
      </div>`;
        itemsContainer.innerHTML += content;
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};

getData();
```

Comment: You can see an example here : https://ipstemplate.com/indexdemo/

Comment: Hide your API key from your code sample. If not, somebody can use and corrupt or steal your data!!!